# Virtual Serial Port access using C and MinGW on Windows 7 x64

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port, mingw

I'm trying to communicate with a virtual serial port using MinGW on a Windows 7 x64 machine. According to the Device Manager my device is available at `COM27`. I have this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        HANDLE hComm;

        const WCHAR FileFullPath[] = {L"COM1"} ;


        hComm = CreateFile( (LPCTSTR)FileFullPath,
                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                            0,
                            0,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                            0);

        if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            printf("Invalid value: %d\r\n", GetLastError());
        }
    }
```

Which gives me a `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` ([error code 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Output:

```
Invalid value: 2
```

If I change the port name to `COM1` (another port that I have), fails to create the file with error 1450, or `ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES`.

What am I doing wrong? I accept alternatives to MinGW, it's not mandatory.

Comment: assuming you have `UNICODE` defined, the cast to `LPCTSTR` is unnecessary; without `UNICODE`, you'd have to call `CreateFileW` manually or you'll incorrectly call `CreateFileA` with a wide-char string...

Comment: After a few searchs I've found that the port name should be "\\\\.\\COM1" instead of "COM1". That solved the problem. And yes, @Christoph, tha cast is unnecessary I'm just storing on a char array.

Comment: If this question is solved, please post your solution as an answer and accept it (see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The COM port name should be `\\.\COM1` (`\\\\.\\COM1` after escaping the backslashes), not `COM1`.

Answer (score 0):

try CreateFileA

I had the same problem when using Qt and mingw, changing to CreateFileA worked for me. I was already using "\\\\.\\COM??"